# adding image to word using word-interop

Tags: c#, vsto, word-interop

i am trying to insert an image with the hyper link the below is my code

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            WordApp.Documents.Add();

            WordApp.Visible = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range drange = doc.Range();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape picture = 
            drange.InlineShapes.AddPicture("c:\\logo.png", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            // noew add the hyperlink to object of inlineshape
            drange.Hyperlinks.Add(picture, "http:\\www.google.com", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

but when i run the project i get an error
[image]
does any one know why this happens or how i can go about fixing it

Comment: I see you wrote `http:\\www..` in your code; does Word really expect a single backslash rather than a double forward slash (i.e. `http://www...`) in links?

Comment: I executed the code with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 15.0.4797.1003 but didn't got the exception.

Comment: @CaiusJard focus on the problem at hand please.

Comment: @James the version i am using is `Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;                            
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application objApplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection objSelection = objApplication.Selection;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs p = objSelection.Paragraphs;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range objRange = objSelection.Range;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ils = objRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\..\image.PNG");
float scaledWidth = ils.Width;
float scaledHeight = ils.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Word object model doesn't accept an inline shape as an anchor for the [Hyperlinks.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlinks.add) method. Try using a range object instead. Also you may try to use a macro recorder to discover what object is required as an anchor.